# Select email message from multiple PHP variables using $_POST

Tags: php, forms

I'm pretty new to PHP, so I apologize if my terminology is off. I will try to be as detailed as possible. I am trying to store several messages as variables and use $_POST to select the correct message and add it to the email. For example,

```
$message1 ="message content";
$message2 ="message content";
$message3 ="message content";

//send email
$email = $_POST['email'] ;
$message = $_POST['content'] ;
mail($email, "Test Subject",
$message, "From: test@example.com");
echo "success";
```

In my HTML form, the content field picks the message to send (`input name="content" type="hidden" value="message3"`).

Currently, this will simply send an email with a body identical to the value of the form. I think I need to inset $ before the value, so that the variable is used rather than the text alone, but I can't figure out how to do that. I have tried the following, but got a message with an empty body.

```
$message = $_POST[$ . 'content']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an associative array:

```
$messages = array('message1' => 'message content',
                  'message2' => 'message content',
                  'message3' => 'message content');
```

Then do:

```
$message = $messages[$_POST['content']];
```